# VBA Excel Textbox clear after msg box appear

Tags: excel, vba, userform

My code looks for an ID in the column "A", if its a match, then throws a msg so the user can´t re enter another person with the same ID. I wanted something simple and effective, so this works. The problem is when i clear the value, it pop ups again the same msg box, even when the textbox is clear. Any way to solve this issue?

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

    Dim controlrow
    Dim lookrow

    controlrow = Me.TextBox1.Value
    Set lookrow = Hoja4.Range("A:A").Find(What:=controlrow, LookIn:=xlValues)

    If Me.TextBox1.Value = lookrow.Value Then
    MsgBox "El ID ya existe"
    Me.TextBox1.Value = ""
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Something is wrong in your code other than re-firing the `Change_Event`. If `lookrow` is `Nothing` your code will error out on `If Me.TextBox1.Value = lookrow.Value Then`. Naturally one would **a)** turn on/off events to overcome your initial problem, and **b)** check `If Not lookrow Is Nothing Then` continue your code when a match has been found. *Sidenote:* Not specifying all `Range.Find` parameters might result in unwanted results. What if you are searching `xlPart` previously? These settings are "stored" in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amend your code to first check if the textbox is blank.

As mentioned by @JvdV, you also need to code for the possibility that the value you are searching for is never found. When that happens, you will error out for trying to compare `Something` to `Nothing`

---

```
Private Sub Textbox1_Change()

If Me.TextBox1.Value = "" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim controlrow
Dim lookrow As Range

controlrow = Me.TextBox1.Value
Set lookrow = Hoja4.Range("A:A").Find(controlrow, LookIn:=xlValues)

If Not lookrow Is Nothing Then
    If Me.TextBox1.Value = lookrow.Value Then
        MsgBox "El ID ya existe"
        Me.TextBox1.Value = ""
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This Works! Cheers!

Comment: You should address @JvdV's comment on your post. You do need to code for the possibility that the value you are searching for is not found. When that happens, you will error out for trying to compare something to `Nothing`

Comment: I´m looking into that right now, because it happend.

Comment: Really helpful, you and all the ones who gave advice!